# What is the best aproach in limiting django model entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model `Events` that has a `ForeignKey` to `Users`. What will be the best approach to limit users to post only one event. In the models, in the view or both?

I've set a variable in `settings.py` because at some point the users will be able to increase their "quota" of events so a `OneToOneField` isn't an option.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that the defaults are set to `Users`.

My logic was this:
I have two types of users. One type that can only have one entry in `Events` but at some point they can increase their 'quota' and will be allowed to enter more events based on `default` + `increased quota`.

The other type of users can have as many entries in `Events` as they want.

I thought that putting the limit on the `Users` table was more reasonable than to set limits on the `Events`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal to validate events count.

I'd add field number to event table and unique key by (user_id, number)

`pre_save` get last number from events and compare it with `quota` if last number greater then `quote` - raise an error

unique index need to ensure that two events won't save parallely

Comment: I would agree with this answer, so long as the maximum number of events is not user specific. Since in that case you will not be able to avoid entering the User model which creates dependencies of a type of which I am personally not a fan.

Comment: The problem with pre-save is you can't tell if it is a new save or just re-saving an existing model (that's right, right?). So, things might get whacky if an extra object does slip through. I would see if it works in post_save, which has a check for NEW, rather than pre_save.

Comment: @SamBobel Yes, Django is not provide a `created` attribute in `pre_save` however you can check is it new or not: e.g. check that  `instance.pk is None` or use more relable check `sender.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).count() == 0`

Comment: @Dragos I don't see any problem in updated version of question. In signal you can access to user instance and get a limit of events for each user.

Comment: Is there anyway to redirect with pre_save? Or it's just raising errors?

Comment: Yes - just raising errors. Because pre_save know nothing about request.